# Ruby Time.at show different timezone

Tags: ruby, timezone-offset

I currently have my system's timezone set to `+4`. However, when I run `Time.at(0)` the timezone appears as `+3`.

```
2.0.0p353 :001 > Time.now
=> 2013-12-02 17:52:52 +0400
2.0.0p353 :002 > Time.at(0)
=> 1970-01-01 03:00:00 +0300
```

Why is `Time.at(0)` showing the wrong timezone?

Comment: I cannot duplicate this. What is your system?

Comment: Perhaps in your timezone DST is now in effect and on 1970-1-1 it wasn't?

Comment: Or maybe DST wasn't in effect in that timezone on Dec 2 but it is on Jan 1.

Comment: Based on Cyrillic name of OP, he is from Russia and they moved to "summer time" all year long a couple of years ago. So that's why the difference.

Comment: i'm from Russia and yes, since 2011 we have summer time +4. Really, in 1979 we had Timezone +3